# Offline Javascript Ran Autoupdating Calculator and Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, spreadsheet, openoffice.org

**Description:**

I need to make a spreadsheet type calculator to track information from an Online game (ArcheAge). This "spreadsheet" must hold information and auto update one set of values in increments of 5 minutes (Preferably saved as file to their computer. this is an off-line application I am working on).

**Details:**

I was asked to assist in setting up an OpenOffice spreadsheet to track and save information. Most of the data is manually entered and saved on the spreadsheet they already made, however he was having an issue getting one field to auto-update in increments of 5 minutes.

I took a look at what he had and tried to set up a simple (labor = labor + 10 [every 5 minutes]) type of formula, but since spreadsheets cannot use circular reference it was impossible to get that field to auto-update every 5 minutes.

The spreadsheet has 9 columns of data and 24 rows of groups. The columns are (id)(charName)(labor)(freeLabor)(vocation)(tokens)(timeOnline)(realTime)(subscription), plus he added a cell to hold the date and another to hold the time (both from system clock - Date() and Now()).

Each row is 1 character's information (what would consider a database table).

He wants the (labor) values for each character to auto-update every 5 minutes with the value of **New** labor (labor = labor + 10), but this is a circular reference and spreadsheets cannot do this function (at least without a third party program or add-in, as far as I can tell).

So, I looked at it and tried t find a work around. Looked up lots of posts online and came close to finding a solution, however none helped with what we need to do. As a result, I offered to set-up a .html doc for him to use Off-Line and code it to work like a spreadsheet. The code is below.

**Needs:**
Edited: Reference Change 3 below.

i need to try and find a way to have this form data saved to a file on the host PC (off-line) so the user does not have to manually re-enter all of the data every time the form is ran.

**Note - This section changed below this line.**

I need a Non-PhP (javascript and html, or other method) solution to value increment the labor cells for each character set to increase by 10 points every 5 minutes. He wants the cell data to be modifiable without breaking the code (something like getData, run code to increment, and rewrite the new value to the cell). I want to also try and get the code to save to file, so he doesn't have to re-enter the values every time he runs the document.

The solution should display the data like a table, spreadsheet, or database while using html and javascript. If you have another solution method, please feel free to add your thoughts on how I can get this data table created.

Edit 1: I thought I should mention that the value of (Labor) should not ever exceed 5,000 and cannot go below 0. - added 01:43 27Apr2016

Edit 2: Added a better identification of what is needed in the "Needs" block. - added 01:51 27 Apr 2016

Edit 3: Modified first Javascript code for Labor Calculations. It is now a nested **if** statement inside a **for** loop and runs perfectly now. Now al lI need is a way to save form data to the document, or a separate document for the program to call on (if possible). Updated Needs section. - 05:52 27 Apr 2016

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<section>
<!-- Used to create time stamp at top of page. -->
<p id="time"></p>

<!-- Name of page. -->
<header style="text-align: center;">ArcheAge Test Calculator</header>
<br />

<!-- The Form shown on the page. -->
<form id-form1" name="testcalc">
    <!-- Nested Table in Form.-->
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Character Name</th>
            <th>Labor</th>
            <th>Free Labor</th>
            <th>Vocation</th>
            <th>Tokens</th>
            <th>Time/Online</th>
            <th>Subscription</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name1" value="Solareclipse" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor1" value="" name="labor"/></th>
            <td><input type="text" id="free1" value="Test data" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation1" value="Test data" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens1" value="Test data" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online1" value="Test data" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub1" value="Test data" name="sub"/></td>        
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name2" value="Farmergirl" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor2"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free2" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation2" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens2" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online2" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub2" value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name3" value="Peacemaker" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor3"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free3" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation3" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens3" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online3" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub3" value="" name="sub"/></td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name4" value="Irene" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor4"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free4" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation4" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens4" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online4" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub4" value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name5" value="Admiral" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor5"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free5" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation5" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens5" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online5" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub5" value="" name="sub"/></td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name6" value="Huffer" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor6"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free6" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation6" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens6" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online6" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub6" value="" name="sub"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name7" value="Sisco" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor7"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free7" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation7" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens7" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online7" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub7" value="" name="sub"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name8" value="Martha" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor8"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free8" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation8" value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens8" value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online8" value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub8" value="" name="sub"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name9" value="Octavia" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor9"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free9" value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation9"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens9"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online9"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub9"value="" name="sub"/></td>  
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name10" value="Samantha" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor10"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free10"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation10"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens10"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online10"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub10"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name11" value="Joker" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor11"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free11"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation11"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens11"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online11"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub11"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name12" value="GoodKush" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor12"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free12"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation12"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens12"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online12"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub12"value="" name="sub"/></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name13" value="Minerguy" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor13"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free13"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation13"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens13"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online13"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub13"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name14" value="Lunareclipse" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor14"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free14"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation14"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens14"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online14"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub14"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name15" value="Peacemaker" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor15"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free15"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation15"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens15"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online15"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub15"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name16" value="Minergirl" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor16"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free16"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation16"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens16"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online16"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub16"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name17" value="Commander" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor17"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free17"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation17"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens17"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online17"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub17"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name18" value="Minerguyy" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor18"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free18"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation18"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens18"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online18"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub18"value="" name="sub"/></td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name19" value="Odoo" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor19"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free19"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation19"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens19"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online19"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub19"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name20" value="Pheobe" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor20"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free20"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation20"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens20"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online20"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub20"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name21" value="Spacewalker" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor21"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free21"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation21"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens21"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online21"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub21"value="" name="sub"/></td>         
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name22" value="Drunkflowers" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor22"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free22"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation22"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens22"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online22"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub22"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name23" value="Joker" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor23"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free23"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation23"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens23"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online23"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub23"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" id="name24" value="Badkush" name="charname"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="labor24"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="free24"value="" name="freelabor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="vocation24"value="" name="voc"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="tokens24"value="" name="token"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="online24"value="" name="online"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="sub24"value="" name="sub"/></td>     
        </tr>   
    </table><!-- End Table -->
</form><!-- End Form -->
```

**JavaScript**

```js
<!-- Script to run Labor calculations. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 function increment(){
  for(var i=1; i<=24; i++){
   var id = "labor"+i;
   var points = document.getElementById(id).value;
   if(points>=4990){
    document.getElementById(id).value=5000;
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById(id).value=Number(document.getElementById(id).value)+10;
   }
  }
 }
 increment()
</script>

<!-- Script to run Time Stamp at top of page. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
 var date = new Date();
 var n = date.toDateString();
 var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
 
 document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = n + ' ' + time;
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't really said what your problem is, so instead I'm going to introduce you to the magic of for loops.

Instead of writing out the same line 24 times, write this code once!

```
for(var i=1; i<=24; i++){
    var id = "labor" + i;
    var n = Number(document.getElementById(id).innerHTML);
    n += 10;
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = n;
}
```

Explanation:

The for loop creates a variable `i` at the beginning, and sets it to 1. For the first loop, we need the text "labor1", so create another variable id which is the concatenation of "labor" with whatever i is (right now, 1).

Then do your `document.getElementById("labor1").value` thingy, but since the variable id is already "labor1" we can replace it in the loop. The += 10 bit is just shorthand for "add 10 to this value."

The for loop then checks to see that i is less than 24 (it is) and the i++ bit adds 1 to i (so it's 2 now). Then the loop repeats the same code 23 more times, until i > 24.

If you were clever you could create the page programmatically as well, since it looks like a lot of your elements are repeated there.

Comment: Thanks for your input fruitoftheloins. I added a little more detail of what I need in the Needs section of the post. I will take into account the loop in a future iteration.

Comment: also, your loop just appends the number 10 to whatever the current value is. So, if I start with 0, it makes the value 10. When it cycles again, it makes it 1010, then 101010, and so on.